# How can I concatenate multiple variables in my MVC3 Razor code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have some razor code and I am having a problem with getting the syntax working. The code is as follows:

```
else
{
   @(x.RowKey.Substring(0, 2).TrimStart('0') + "." + x.RowKey.Substring(2, 2).TrimStart('0').PadLeft(1, '0')) - @Html.Raw(x.Title)<br>
}
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1002: ; expected
```

Comment: <text>@String.Format("{0}.{1}",x.RowKey.Substring(0, 2).TrimStart('0'),x.RowKey.Substring(2, 2).TrimStart('0').PadLeft(1, '0')) - @Html.Raw(x.Title)<br/></text>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start your `@(x.RowKey....`, Razor still thinks that it's still in C# mode, not HTML mode (to use the totally non-technical terms). Nick Bork's suggestion about wrapping that stuff in the `<text>` tags gets the page back into HTML mode so you can go back to using your normal Razor syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
else
{
   var st = x.RowKey.Substring(0, 2).TrimStart('0') + "." + x.RowKey.Substring(2, 2).TrimStart('0').PadLeft(1, '0'));

   @st - @Html.Raw(x.Title)<br/>
}
```